# How to do user accounts in a clojure web app?

Tags: session, web-applications, authentication, clojure

I'm trying to write a clojure web app, and I'd like to let people make user accounts and login and logout, in the way that something like reddit or hacker news do.

I'm completely new to this, and I get the impression that it's a bit subtle and complicated. googling hasn't helped much.

Could anyone point me to an article discussing the problem and approaches to solving it in general, and a tutorial showing how to do it in clojure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of handling authentication and web apps in general, depending on your requirements. Generally, I suggest using an existing clojure library (for web applications or authentication) and figuring out how they work in specific. You can start with [Moustache](https://github.com/cgrand/moustache) to get your web app going and then continue by using [Friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend) to add authentication. I personally haven't used either of these and have implemented basic authentication with compojure but these libaries look ok to me for getting the job done.

Answer (score 0):

This question also came up on the [Clojure email group.](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/clojure/ZytyHzOjwdw/discussion) Many people suggested Mozilla's [Persona](https://login.persona.org/) authentication system because it was the easiest to use.